# issues with freeing memory/ cross platform compatability

Tags: c, gcc, tree, free, runtime-error

I made a tree in C, everything works on my computer when I use Visual C++ except for the free function.

I'm also having lots of issues at run time when I compile on any other platform (gcc on both DOS and UNIX). I have no idea whats wrong there.

On my Visual C++ debugger it breaks at (1)

```
void freePhoneBook(PhoneBookP P)
{
    traverseFree(P->Root);
}
static void traverseFree(NodeP N)
{
    if(N)
    {
        traverseFree(N->Left);
        traverseFree(N->Right);
        free(N);//(1)<------fails here
    }
}
```

Error says:

Heap block at 00A01768 modified at 00A01798 past requested size of 28
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in PhoneBook.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in PhoneBook.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while PhoneBook.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
HEAP[PhoneBook.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00A00000, 00A01770 )
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in PhoneBook.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in PhoneBook.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while PhoneBook.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.

Here's all my code:

```
    /*
 * PhoneBook.h
 * Cop 3530 
 * jlewis
 */

#ifndef _phonebook_h
#define _phonebook_h

/*
 * PhoneBookP is a pointer to the phonebook struct
 * Define the phonebook struct and the node struct 
 * in your (.c) file
 */
typedef struct PhoneBookT *PhoneBookP;

/*
 * PhoneBook Interface
 */

/*
 * Returns a pointer to a new empty PhoneBook
 * If memory cannot be allocated, returns a NULL pointer
 */
PhoneBookP newPhoneBook();

/*
 * Locates and displays the desired entry from the phone book
 * If entry is not found, display an appropriate message
 * Parameters: book, firstname, lastname
 */
void lookupPhoneBook(PhoneBookP, char *);

/*
 * Creates node with the provided data
 * Inserts the node into the correct position in the tree
 * NOTE: Copy the data into the node
 */
void insertPhoneBook(PhoneBookP, char *, char *);

/*
 * Removes the node containing the matching names
 * Parameters: phonebook, firstname
 * Returns true if successful, else false
 *
 * NOTE: THIS FUNCTION IS FOR BONUS POINTS
 * YOU CAN SIMPLY INSERT A DUMMY FUNCTION THAT 
 * ALWAYS RETURNS ZERO IF YOU CHOOSE
 */
int removePhoneBook(PhoneBookP, char *);

/*
 * Dislpays all the entries in the Phone book in order
 * Display one person per line, firstname followed by phone number
 */
void displayPhoneBook(PhoneBookP);

/*
 * Frees the memory used by each node in the book
 * Frees the memory used by this addressbook
 */
void freePhoneBook(PhoneBookP);

#endif
```

Heres the .c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "PhoneBook.h"
typedef struct NodeT
{
    struct NodeT *Left;
    struct NodeT *Right;
    char *Name;
    char *Number;
}* NodeP;

struct PhoneBookT
{
    NodeP Root;
};
static void Insert(PhoneBookP, NodeP, char* Name,char* Number);
static void traversePrint(NodeP N);
static NodeP newNode(PhoneBookP P, NodeP, char *Name,char *Number);
static int find(NodeP N,char *Name);
static void traverseFree(NodeP N);
PhoneBookP newPhoneBook()
{
    PhoneBookP P =(PhoneBookP) malloc(sizeof(PhoneBookP));
    P->Root = NULL;
    return P;
}
void lookupPhoneBook(PhoneBookP P, char * Name)
{
    if(find(P->Root, Name));
    else printf("Error\n");
}
static int find(NodeP N,char *Name)
{
    if(N)
    {
        find(N->Left,Name);
        if(0 == strcmp(Name,N->Name))
        {
            printf("Name: %s\nNumber: %s\n", N->Name, N->Number);
            return 1;
        }
        find(N->Right,Name);
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
void insertPhoneBook(PhoneBookP P, char *Name, char *Number)
{
    if(P->Root)
        Insert(P, P->Root, Name,Number);
    else
        P->Root = newNode(P,P->Root, Name,Number);
}
static void Insert(PhoneBookP P,NodeP N,  char* Name,char* Number)
{
    if(N)
    {
        if(0 > strcmp(Name,N->Name))
        {
            if(N->Left)
            {
                Insert(P,N->Left, Name, Number);
            }
            else
            {
                N->Left = newNode(P,N->Left, Name, Number);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(N->Right)
            {
                Insert(P,N->Right, Name, Number);
            }
            else
            {
                N->Right = newNode(P,N->Right, Name, Number);
            }
        }
    }
    else
        N = newNode(P, N, Name, Number);
}
static NodeP newNode(PhoneBookP P,NodeP N,char *Name,char *Number)
{
    NodeP New = (NodeP) malloc(sizeof(NodeP));
    N = New;
    New->Left = NULL;
    New->Right = NULL;
    New->Name = Name;
    New->Number = Number;
    return New;
}
int removePhoneBook(PhoneBookP P, char * Name)
{
    return 0;
}
void displayPhoneBook(PhoneBookP P)
{
    traversePrint(P->Root);
}
static void traversePrint(NodeP N)
{
    if(N)
    {
        traversePrint(N->Left);
        printf("Name: %s\n", N->Name);
        printf("Number: %s\n", N->Number);
        traversePrint(N->Right);
    }
}
void freePhoneBook(PhoneBookP P)
{
    traverseFree(P->Root);
}
static void traverseFree(NodeP N)
{
    if(N)
    {
        traverseFree(N->Left);
        traverseFree(N->Right);
        free(N);
    }
}
```

Here's The Tester
I didn't make the remove function, so don't use that.

```
/*
 * PhoneBookTest.h
 * Cop 3411 Spr11
 * jlewis
 */

#include "PhoneBook.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    PhoneBookP myBook = newPhoneBook();
    printf("Book contains (Joe, Sue, Tom, Vince, Zachary)\n");
    insertPhoneBook(myBook, "Sue", "800-444-4444");
    insertPhoneBook(myBook, "Joe", "555-5555");
    insertPhoneBook(myBook, "Tom", "111-1111");
    insertPhoneBook(myBook, "Zachary", "1-888-888-8888");
    insertPhoneBook(myBook, "Vince", "333-3333");
    displayPhoneBook(myBook);
    printf("\nLooking for Sue ... ");
    lookupPhoneBook(myBook, "Sue");
    printf("Looking for Tom ... ");
    lookupPhoneBook(myBook, "Tom");
    printf("Looking for Zac ... ");
    lookupPhoneBook(myBook, "Zachary");
/*
    fprintf(stderr, "\nRemoving Joe\n");
    removePhoneBook(myBook, "Joe");
    displayPhoneBook(myBook);
*/
    printf("\nAdding 5 more ... Al, Jason, Thomas, Billy, Tommy\n");
    insertPhoneBook(myBook, "Al", "888-8888");
    insertPhoneBook(myBook, "Jason", "888-8888");
    insertPhoneBook(myBook, "Thomas", "888-8888");
    insertPhoneBook(myBook, "Billy", "888-8888");
    insertPhoneBook(myBook, "Tommy", "888-8888");
    displayPhoneBook(myBook);
   /*
    fprintf(stderr, "\nRemoving Thomas\n");
    //removePhoneBook(myBook, "Thomas");
    displayPhoneBook(myBook);
    fprintf(stderr, "\nRemoving Zachary\n");
    //removePhoneBook(myBook, "Zachary");
    displayPhoneBook(myBook);*/
    freePhoneBook(myBook);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help Is much appreciated

Also this is due at 4pm central time.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a lot of code. You should narrow it down to the error by using a debugger and show us a more concise piece of code that still shows produces the error.

Comment: Run your code under a debugger or valgrind to help identify problems and fix bugs.

Comment: Also take note of the advice given in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299723/assigning-a-pointer-in-a-struct-to-a-variable) and do not cast the result of malloc.

Answer (score 1):

One major bug is that you are passing `sizeof(PhoneBookP)` to malloc when you should be passing `sizeof(struct PhoneBookT)` or `sizeof(*P)`.

Comment: `typedef struct PhoneBookT *PhoneBookP;` I believe This should address that.

Comment: Abd similarly for `NodeP`'s `malloc()` call

Comment: I get a syntax error when I give sizeof a pointer to the pointer.